# custome tab header in lwuit resource editor

Tags: java-me, lwuit, codenameone

I am trying to make a codename one application in which i have to use tabbed form. 
I made a form having tab container which has three container to show three tabs.
But these three tab header looks bulky, there heights is very big for my UI.

How can we edit its height?
Can we make own tab header if yes then how?
Can we use any type of renderer in it.

can it be done using lwuit res editor or i have to do it in code.

Please help.

Comment: Is that supposed to be a picture? There is nothing there? Did you use the Tabs component?

Comment: Yes sir, i uses tabs component in res editor and add two containers in tabs component. i assign them only name(Text) not image. images are null.

Comment: There is a gray square in your post, is that image? if so what does it represent?

Comment: Sorry sir, its nothing. Actually stack-overflow says that my question does not match required credentials that's why I add blank code space in question. I really sorry about it.

Comment: I removed the empty code, was really confusing, I thought it was an image ;-)

Comment: Its ok sir, But i want my own tab header. how can i ? please help.

Answer (score 0):

Just define the Tab border to empty and it will remove the border thus shrinking the size the tab takes up. Do the same for the TabsContainer UIID and the size the tabs take up should be very small. If you want it to still look good just define a new "smaller" border that suites your requirements.

Comment: I did not assign any border to any component in my resource file. I just take a tab component in resource file and add two container in it. nothing else. Its look good in google nexux (High resolution) but looks huge in samsung fit(Low resolution). Any idea? how we can resolve it. Either by assigning height or with own tab system? Please suggest.

Comment: The native theme assigns a border. It seems to be missing a low resolution version of the border. My suggestion will work around this issue, I also suggest filing an issue in the Codename One issue tracker.